# Mongoose + express でネストされたスキーマモデルをsaveしたい．

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

現在ExpressとMongooseで jsonAPIを作成しております．
2つのモデルを合成してsaveしたいです．

```
// app/models/room.js

var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var TmpSchema    = require('./tmp');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var RoomSchema   = new Schema({
    users: [TmpSchema],
    host_user: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Room', RoomSchema);'
```

こちらは子となるモデルです．

```
// app/models/tmp.js

var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var TmpSchema = new Schema({
    user_id : String
} , { _id: false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tmp', TmpSchema);
```

このような状態の時，POSTメソッドが呼び出された時にroomモデルのレコードを保存したいです．

```
// server.js

// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// use MongoDB
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/edisonHTTPRequestAPI'); // connect to our database

// use Model
var User       = require('./app/models/user');
var Room       = require('./app/models/room');
var Tmp        = require('./app/models/tmp');

~~~~

router.route('/rooms')

// create a users (accessed at POST http://localhost:3000/api/rooms)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        var room = new Room();
        room.host_user = req.body.host_user;
        if(req.query.userID != null){
            var users = req.query.userID.split(" ");
            for(var i = 0;i<users.length;i++){
                var tmp = new Tmp();
                tmp.user_id = users[i];
                tmp.save();
                room.users[i] = tmp;
            }
        }

        room.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            console.log(room);
            res.json({ message: 'Room created!' });
        });
    })
```

上記の様な記述を行いました．

そこで，例えば以下のようにPOSTメソッドを叩くと，意図したjsonが帰ってきます．
[image]

また，`server.js`内で，`console.log(room)`と行うと，ログも以下のように正常な値が帰ってきます．

```
{ __v: 0,
  host_user: 'test',
  _id: 5667de123b5a5caf9c000001,
  users: 
   [ { __v: 0, user_id: 'abc' },
     { __v: 0, user_id: 'def' },
     { __v: 0, user_id: 'ghi' } ] }
```

しかし，このidを用いてsaveしたデータを確認すると，データの中にusersの要素が含まれていませんでした．

`$ curl http://localhost:3000/api/rooms/5667de123b5a5caf9c000001`

```
//result
{"_id":"5667de123b5a5caf9c000001","host_user":"test","__v":0,"users":[]}
```

これは何が原因なのでしょうか…
ご教授願います．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ネストされたスキーマモデル（embedded document）が更新されない場合、多分 `markModified` を忘れているんじゃないかな。

`room.save()` を実行する前に `room.markModified('users');` と入れてみたらどうでしょう？

これを入れてもダメなら `Schema.options.toJSON` あたりを調べてみるのが、吉と思われ。